# React Native npm run eject error when i try to emulate my app in an android emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm going to create a very simple react native app according to the instructions given in [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_environment_setup.htm)

when I get to the point where we eject the app to use in android device or android studio emulator i get the following error:

[image]

i do what this page says step by step. i've installed react native and react native cli and all the required files.
can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow Facebook's instructions, that's more than enough [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started)

And navigate tab React Native CLI Quickstart

Comment: Thanks. I think i should do